# Using Bluetooth keyboard and mouse via Remote Desktop

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, windows, remote-access, mouse

I occasionally use my Galaxy S4 Android phone to connect to my computer via Remote Desktop in order to use SolidWorks for 3d modeling.  In order to make this more comfortable, I want to get a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard.  What I'm wondering is whether the keys translate well when I am connected to my computer.

In other words: the keys probably translate well enough when I am just using the phone.  However, the phone does not tend to utilize keys the same way Windows does - ctrl-c, alt-F1, etc..  Do those functions/keys translate when I'm connected to my computer through my phone?

And a similar question for a Bluetooth mouse, I suppose.  Does the computer recognize a mouse when it is connected through my phone via Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they will work. If the keyboard & mouse supports windows, then they should work via remote desktop. Be sure to have the latest version of the app!

Comment: PS: you may have to install some kind or compatibility apps or drivers on your phone.

Comment: Ok - got me a keyboard and mouse.  The keyboard works great.  The mouse works well on Microsoft Remote Desktop app, but is pretty wonky on Google Remote Desktop.  I can connect to my computer on my phone when I'm on the same network, but out-of-network MS RD it's still not connecting (although Goodle RD is).  This is probably a topic for another question post.  But yeah, hardware-wise everything is good.  Still figuring out the mouse, but the more important thing - the keyboard - is working regardless.  Thanks Rahul! :D